# Spring JMS listener acknowledge

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I am using JMS to send receive message from IBM MQ message broker. I am currently working on listener service throwing unhandled excepion and message sent 
back to queue without acknowledgement. 
I want the service to retry a configurable number of time and throw meaning full exception message that listener service is unavailable.

My listener and container factory looks like below.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "testqueue", containerFactory = "queuejmsfactory")
public void consumer(String message) throws JMSException 
{ handle(message); }

@Bean(name = "queuejmsfactory") public JmsListenerContainerFactory getQueueTopicFactory(ConnectionFactory con , 
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer config) 
{ DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory d = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory(); 
d.setSessionTransacted(true); 
d.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
config.configure(d,con); 
return d; }
```

I short, I have an existing code using the SessionawareMessageListener onMessage which i am trying to 
replicate to @JmsListener. How do i handle the session commit and rollback automatically and 
how do i get the session in JmsListener if have to handle manually similar to onMessage.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Mesage mes, Session ses) throws JMSException 
{ try 
{ TestMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage)message; 
handle(txtMessage); ses.commit(); 
} catch (Exception exp) 
{ if (shouldRollback(message))
{ ses.rollback();} 
else{logger,warn("moved to dlq"); 
ses.commit(); 
} 
} }

private boolean shouldRollback(Message mes) throws JMSException 
{ int rollbackcount = mes.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount"); 
return (rollbackcount <= maxRollBackCountFromApplication.properties)
}
```

Updated code:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "testqueue", containerFactory = "queuejmsfactory")
    public void consumer(Message message) throws JMSException 
    { 
        try {TestMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage)message;
            handle(txtMessage);}
        catch(Excepton ex) {
            if shouldRollback(message)
            {throw ex;}
            else {logger.warn("moved to dlq")}

    }}

    private boolean shouldRollback(Message mes) throws JMSException 
    { int rollbackcount = mes.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount"); 
    return (rollbackcount <= maxRollBackCountFromApplication.properties)
    }

    @Bean(name = "queuejmsfactory") public JmsListenerContainerFactory getQueueTopicFactory(ConnectionFactory con , 
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer config) 
    { DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory d = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory(); 
    d.setSessionTransacted(true); 
    d.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
    config.configure(d,con); 
    return d; }
```

I have also tried to access the JMSXDeliveryCount from Headers, but couldnt get the exact object to access delivery count. Can you clarify plz.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "testqueue", containerFactory = "queuejmsfactory")
    public void consumer(Message message,
                               @Header(JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) String correlationId,
                               @Header(name = "jms-header-not-exists") String nonExistingHeader,
                               @Headers Map<String, Object> headers,
                               MessageHeaders messageHeaders,
                               JmsMessageHeaderAccessor jmsMessageHeaderAccessor) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `Session` as another parameter to the `JmsListener` method.

Comment: Thanks Gary, so in that case if i pass the session to jmslistener and handling sessioncommit and rollback manually  in the similar way, should i need d.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); ?
or what should be the acknowledge mode.

Comment: Using `@jmsListener`,is this the best approach to acheive te use case? Is there a better option am missing. We are also using RabitMQ for development environment and using `@RabbitListener`, any lead to implement the same method in amqp will be also helpful.

Comment: It's exactly the same as the old listener. With auto mode, the container will ack the message before calling the listener. You really don't need to mess with the session yourself; just throw an exception to roll back the transaction and exit normally to commit. You should ask a separate question about RabbitMQ. Don't ask new questions in comments here.

Comment: My jmslistener and containr factory code in the original post is suggested in your view?My requirement is to keep track of retry count and then log meaning exception in consumer end when it exceeds configurable limit. Is it acheivable without handling session ?

Comment: It's not necessary to mess with the session in your existing code; as I said, throw an exception until the delivery count is exceeded and the container will roll back or commit the transaction. With the `@JmsListener` you can either receive the complete `Message` or you can get the converted payload and the delivery count in a `@Header` parameter.

Comment: edited original question with latest code i am using.comment if any I have also tried to access the JMSXDeliveryCount from Headers, but couldnt get the exact object to access delivery count. Can you clarify .